# Apache Rewrite urls - remove .html and return 404 if .html is present

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am adding a directory to a website that is served with Apache 2 that I want to drop the .html extension from incoming requests. In /new-directory I have a .htaccess file containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

So with this rule /new-directory/page works, but /new-directory/page.html also works, which I don't want. I want all pages in new-directory/ and sub-directories to only serve pages *without* .html, and return a 404 not found if a page.html request comes in.

These are new pages so I don't care about redirecting.

**Edit:** 
Forgot to mention that there is only one file in /new-directory (/new-directory/dhandler) - a Perl script that parses the incoming url if there is a matching database entry. There are no files to match so I can drop that condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, my fault that I didn't explain that there is only one default file handler in /new-directory which lead to some confusion, see edit above - anyway this worked:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*\.html[\s\?]{1}
RewriteRule .*\.html$ - [R=404,L]
```

What messed me up was that sometimes these urls will have query strings so I have to check for both space and ? to match .html in %{THE_REQUEST}.

**EDIT:** If someone has actual .html files in a directory(instead of one file that dynamically handles all requests like I do) then they should probably add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

right after 'RewriteEngine On' To make sure that the incoming request matches an existing file in /new-directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need a couple of rules to do this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*\.html\s
RewriteRule .*\.html$ - [R=404,L]
```

The first one checks that there is actually an html file that corresponds to the request. If it does, it will internally rewrite the request to that.

The second rule will redirect **anything** that ends `.html` to a 404 not found.

Comment: Copied and pasted this into .htaccess and it doesn't allow for either non-.html or .html pages.

Comment: Made a change to the rules, please try again

Comment: Now that works better. 2 things though- the '-f' doesn't work, I had to change it to '!-f' - maybe  since the request is new-directory/page and what is in the actual directory is new-directory/page.html so there is no match maybe? Second I have a page new-directory/new.html and when this is called instead of rewriting to www.example.com/new-directory/new it rewrites to www.example.com/new and is not found - is this due to the names being similar?

Comment: Maybe your question needs to be clearer... The "-f" is required to make sure that the actual file exists, your new file is probably broken because it's not satisfying that condition. Also, you didn't ask for a rewrite on new-directory/new.html, you asked to return a 404. Adding a new-directory/new.html and calling as new-directory/new works fine for me with the above rules

Comment: You are correct I forgot to mention that the "files" in /new-directory are really handled by one default file that parses the url. So there are no files in the directory to match with. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in `/new-directory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new-directory/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/new-directory/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```